# How IBM Blockchain Platform initializing chaincode? Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I read that IBM Blockchain Platform is using Kubernetes to manage the hyperledger fabric network.

I was wondering how they are initializing the chaincode as it is not a straight forward in the Kubernetes.

There are 2 options which I found:

1. Docker In Docker
2. Manifest File (creating a pod with fabric-tools container and then initializing the chaincode)

How IBM is initializing the chaincodes? Are there any other options other than above 2? If yes, please add a reference of how to use that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.
Docker in Docker is used. Chaincode is initialized by the peers when it is instantiated.

Regards,
Pam